# How does a Fender Greasebucket tone circuit work in a guitar?

Tags: tone-control

I'm a guitar-tech-hobbyist and only slightly educated when it comes to electronics/electricity. I am  trying to understand (at a "Subject for Dummies" level) the flow of current through a Fender guitars Greasebucket circuit and also what actually happens inside the circuit.

A guitar tone circuit essentially acts as a frequency filter/drain, sending some frequencies off to ground before the signal goes out of the guitar.

The Greasebucket adds a 1nF capacitor in series to a standard stratocaster tone pototentiometer.  The standard stratocaster potentiometer has maximum 250k resistance.

In a guitar potentiometer, the end lugs always have maximum resistance between them while the center one varies between the two end lugs based on the position of the sweeper. My thinking is that the green capacitor is acting as a **jumper** which either blocks some of the highs or it allows more lows through.

Here's a drawing of one:

[image]

Here's what I think is happening in the picture:

The signal is going from  pickup (not pictured)

- -> to the switch lugs (top)
- -> to an end lug of the potentiometer,
- -> through the green cap (bypassing the sweeper)
- -> to the center lug,
- -> through the sweeper,
- -> then through the red cap and 4.7k resistor
- -> to ground.

My questions are

1. Am I right about the flow of current?
2. How does a capacitor even work as a filter? I accept that it does, but I do not understand it.

The drawing and a layman's explanation of the circuit can be found here:

[Premiere Guitar Mod Garage](https://www.premierguitar.com/diy/mod-garage/greasebucket-tone-circuit)

Comment: I suggest you draw a a proper schematic of that circuit..that will make it much easier to visualize it for yourself and others and it might become immediately obvious how it works.

Comment: The source input and output wires are no identified clearly nor the guitar impedance

Answer (score 1):

The Greasebucket tone control does not affect low frequencies so it is not a bandpass ciruit. Instead it is another kind of adjustable highs cut circuit.
Here is the schematic from Google:
[image: greasebucket]

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that each filter is identical for dual pickups I added  source Pot.

[This results in 20 to 60Hz LPF and a 488 Hz HPF that cancels the LPF and flattens out with variable attenuation.](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%200%2010523.112161612546%0Aw%20720%20384%20768%20384%200%0A170%20672%20368%20672%20320%202%2020%204000%205%200.1%0AO%20720%20384%20720%20352%200%0Ac%20720%20448%20720%20480%200%202.2000000000000002e-8%200%0Ar%20720%20480%20720%20512%200%204700%0A174%20720%20384%20768%20448%200%20250000%200.9455000000000001%20Resistance%0Ag%20720%20512%20720%20528%200%0Ac%20768%20384%20768%20416%200%201e-7%200%0A174%20624%20384%20720%20368%200%20500000%200.7475%20Resistance%0A)  Determined by the R Ratio for 0 to -23 dB.

Pot's usually don't go to 0 but around 5% (13k/250k) then added series 4k7 makes 17k7 / 250k or 7% =  -23 dB max

[image]